# Changing Color / Fill Property of SVG on Click of Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm building a React App I want to change the `fill` of an svg image on click of a button.

The button/svg image is imported from a separate 'media' folder. With JavaScript, I'm able to select the image but not sure how I can change the fill property.

Basically wanted to change `.st1`'s fill to a different color.

I've tried `chev.style.fill = "newcolor"` and `chev.classList.add("newstyle")` but getting *can't set property of undefined*

```
import chevronRight from './media/chevron-right.svg';

handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let chev = document.querySelector('.nxt_chevron-right').src;
  console.log(chev);
}

<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
 <input
   className="chevron-right"
   type="image"
   src={chevronRight}
   alt="Submit"
 />
</form>
```

SVG

```
<svg>
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#3C444C;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M18.9,0H0v20.9h18.9c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V2C20.9,0.9,20,0,18.9,0z"/>
<g>
    <path class="st1" d="M13.5,10.5L10,5.3C9.8,5.2,9.6,5,9.3,5H7.5l3.4,5.1l0,0l0.3,0.4L10.9,11l-3.4,5h1.8c0.3,0,0.6-0.2,0.7-0.4
        l2.3-3.4L13.5,10.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was my SVG was in referenced externally. So I decided to restructure the button so that the SVG can be referenced inline like so (wrapped around `label` tag):

```
<label>
   <input type="submit" />
     <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 20.9 20.9">
       <path className="arrow-bg"
          d="M18.9,0H0v20.9h18.9c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V2C20.9,0.9,20,0,18.9,0z"
       />
       <g>
       <path className={
           this.state.errors.email
             ? 'arrow-fill-validated'
             : 'arrow-fill'
       }
                  d="M13.5,10.5L10,5.3C9.8,5.2,9.6,5,9.3,5H7.5l3.4,5.1l0,0l0.3,0.4L10.9,11l-3.4,5h1.8c0.3,0,0.6-0.2,0.7-0.4
        l2.3-3.4L13.5,10.5z"
         />
     </g>
   </svg>
</label>
```

Then, I was able to tap into its' css properties and change styling based on state (I changed the way even was handled from onClick to onBlur for email validation)

Answer (score 0):

If it is only ever going to change to one color, you can apply a different classname onClick, that changes a state variable in order to change the class name associated with the color change.

Something along the lines of

`class={ state.isClicked ? classname1 : classname2 }`

Comment: I can't set className since the svg image is referenced as a source within <input> tag.